# SQL Except Syntax in C# Linq

Tags: c#, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have exported the data in datatable in SQL server for testing, and I have ended up with a query of :

```
Select * from @tempTable1
Except
Select * from @tempTable2
```

How can i write this statement in Linq C#? I already have 2 DataTable that represent the @tempTable1 and @tempTable2 in my C# code

Comment: `table1.Except(table2)`?

Comment: table1.AsEnumerable().Except(table2.AsEnumerable(),
                                                    DataRowComparer.Default);

Comment: @vishuminhas is there a way to covert the result to DataTable? I got this error while assign the result to a datatable

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>' to 'System.Data.DataTable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You Can Try This :

```
DataTable dtmismatch = Table1.AsEnumerable().Except(Table2.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default).CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```